# Proving that $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}}dx<+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, beta-function

I got this integral from a probability question in which I am interested to prove that it is $<\infty$
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}}dx,~~~n \ge 1$$

I tried substitution $y =x+1$, but it does not help, so I am thinking maybe a direct integration is not the way to go.  I tried bounding the integrand using $\frac{1}{(1+x)^{n+1}}<1 $ but I get $+\infty$ Any idea, how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{n x^{n - 1}}{(x + 1)^{n + 1}}  \,dx \leq n \int_0^\infty \frac{(x + 1)^{n - 1}}{(x + 1)^{n + 1}} \,dx .$$ N.b. the inequality requires the condition $n - 1 \geq 0$, since only for those values is $x \mapsto x^{n - 1}$ a nondecreasing function.

Comment: This was precisely what I was trying to do. Thank you all!. They are all interesting answers, But I  am accepting this one because is the easiest for me. I didn't know about the beta equivalents and  realizing that there was an antiderivative of a quotient is not so easy.

Comment: -1, Wait, the RHS is divergent. $$n \int_0^\infty \frac{(x + 1)^{n - 1}}{(x + 1)^{n + 1}} \,dx=n\to\infty $$ And how to deal with the $0<n<1$ case, although the OP didn't ask for this case.

Comment: @GGplay I'm not sure I agree that the RHS is divergent. It's $n\left[-(x+1)^{-1}\right]_0^\infty = n$.

Comment: Ah, I thought to prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}}dx<+\infty$$ which is also true, but we can't use the method in this answer.

Comment: @GGplay Gotcha - I thought that might have been it.

Answer (score 8):

The integrand has a direct antiderivative, which we can see by rewriting the terms like so

$$I = \int_0^\infty n\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{n-1}\frac{dx}{(x+1)^2} = \int_0^\infty n\left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^{n-1} d\left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$$
$$ = \left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)^n\Biggr|_0^\infty = 1$$

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}}dx=n\cdot B(n,1)=\frac{n\cdot \Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+1)}=1$$

Comment: The beta function I know is an integral from 0 to 1 ,like this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function .. how did you get that form?.

Comment: @some_math_guy Yes, that's the definition form of beta function, but there are other useful forms. Just scroll down that wiki page to "Other identities and formulas", and you can find other two useful forms. $$B(z_1,z_2) = 2\int_0^{\pi / 2}(\sin\theta)^{2z_1-1}(\cos\theta)^{2z_2-1}\,d\theta$$ and 
  $$  B(z_1,z_2) = \int_0^\infty\frac{t^{z_1-1}}{(1+t)^{z_1+z_2}}\,dt$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}}\,dx=\frac {x^n}{(1+x)^n}$$
$$\int_0^p \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}}\,dx=\left(\frac{p}{p+1}\right)^n=1-\frac{n}{p}+\frac{n (n+1)}{2
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the integral into two, we have
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}} d x =\int_0^{1} \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}} d x+ \int_1^{\infty} \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}} d x
$$
The first integral is finite, we need only to consider the second one by letting $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x} $.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}} d x& =\int_0^1 \frac{n}{(1+x)^{n+1}} d x \\
& =\left[-\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}\right]_0^1 \\
& =-\frac{1}{2^n}+1 \\
& <1
\end{aligned}
$$
So the integral is finite.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}} \sim \frac n{x^2}$ and this guarantees convergence.

More in detail since

$$\frac{\frac{n x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}}}{\frac1{x^2+1}}=\frac{n x^{n+1}+x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+1}}\to n$$

the given integral $I$ converges by limit comparison test with  $\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^2+1}dx$.